# rails convention for http raising errors in controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, model-view-controller, exception

lets say I have an articles_controller with a show method

I want to make sure that only clients with a valid license code can read the json endpoint for this controller action

```
def show
  authenticate_license if params[:format] == 'json' 
  # boilerplate
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @article, status: :ok }
  end
end
```

I might want to use this authentication block somewhere else, so i put it into my application_controller

```
# in application_controller
def authenticate_license
  @client = params[:client]
  licenses = License.where(:code => params[:code])
  @license = licenses.first
  if @license
    if @license.client = @client
      # do nothing, we're fine
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: 'wrong client', status: 400 }
      end
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: 'bad license', status: :forbidden }
    end  
  end
end
```

but this results in a doublerendererror so now i'll try something different

```
# in application_controller
def authenticate_license
  licenses = License.where(:code => params[:code]
  @license = licenses.first
  if @license
    if @license.client = @client
      # do nothing, we're fine
    else
      raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('wrong client')
    end
  else
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('bad license code')
  end
end
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError do |exception|
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message }
    format.json { render json: exception.message, status: :forbidden }
  end
end
```

but this way, I can't specify the HTTP status, and I'm also catching routing errors I probably don't want to catch.

What's the correct way to do what I want to do?

The behavior I'm describing is sort of what devise does. If you make a request to an action that has the authorize_user! method for example, it will raise an error, and redirect the user to some page. CanCan does something similar too, if a user is not authorized to do something, it raises it's own exception that you're supposed to catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is valid, you are rendering morethan one time, that's the reason for `doublerender` exception. It is better to keep rendering in your controller only

Try this code

```
def show
  is_client_valid = authenticate_license if params[:format] == 'json' 
  # boilerplate
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    if is_client_valid == 'valid' #you can have a switch statement here, so that you can easily set the status tag
      format.json { render json: @article, status: :ok }
    else
       format.json { render json: is_client_valid }
    end
  end
end


# in application_controller
def authenticate_license
  @client = params[:client]
  licenses = License.where(:code => params[:code])
  @license = licenses.first
  if @license
    if @license.client = @client
      return 'valid'
    else
        return 'wrong client' 
    end
  else
      return 'bad licence'
  end
end
```

Comment: 'is client_valid'...

was that 'is' a typo? or does ruby/rails have an 'is' keyword...?